# TypeScript explicit `this` parameter in class/interface method

Tags: typescript, this, class-method

For now I use TypeScript and encountered feature(?) I can't figure out on my own by using Google. Could anyone make this clear? The strange thing regards to explicit `this` declaration of a class method. I looked at transpiled javascript and see that first parameter (`this`) is void. So the code actually works. But I would like to know what is this and why is this?

```
class Foo {
    bar(this: Foo, whatever: any) {
        console.log(whatever);
    } 
};

...

const foo = new Foo();
foo.bar({ baz: 'it works properly' });
```

Comment: `this: <type>` is just a hint as to what the context (i.e. the value of the `this` object) within the function will be. It's not an actual parameter

Comment: @apokryfos My guess was the same, but is there any official description of this? Though it's not very important, just an interest... Thanx

Comment: All the documentation I found is https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this